# Docker create two bridges that corrupts my internet access

Tags: linux, networking, docker

I'm facing a pretty strange issue:

Here is my config:

- docker 17-ce
- ubuntu 16.04.

*I work from two differents places with differents internet providers.*

On the first place, everything works just fine, i can run docker out of the box and access internet without any problems.

But on the second place i cannot access the internet while docker is running, ***more precisly while the two virtual briges created by docker are up***.

In this place, internet connection operate very strangly, i can ping google dns at 8.8.8.8, but nearly all dns request failed and most of the time after a few seconds the internet connection is totally down.

( The only difference between the first and the second place is the internet provider ).

At first i tought i could fix that by changing the default network bridge ip, but this does not solve the problem at all.

The point is that the **--bip** option of the docker daemon change the IP of the default docker bridge **docker0**, but docker also create an other bridge called **br-1a0208f108d9** which does not reflect the settings passed to the **--bip** option.

I guess that this second bridge is causing trouble to my network because it overlap my wifi adapter configuration.

I'm having a hard time trying to diagnosticate this.

***My questions are:***

- How can i be sure that my asumptions are right and that this second bridget is in conflict with my wifi adapter
- What is this second bridge ? It's easy to find documentation about the **docker0** bridge, but i cannot find anything related to this second bridge **br-1a0208f108d9**
- How the exact same setup can work on one place and not an other one.

With this trouble i feel like i'm pretty close to level up my docker knowledges but before that i have to increase my network administration knowledges.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. At first I had no clue that docker is the culprit.

Answer (score 9):

I manage to solve this issue after reading this:

https://success.docker.com/Architecture/Docker_Reference_Architecture%3A_Designing_Scalable%2C_Portable_Docker_Container_Networks

The second docker bridge **br-1a0208f108d9** was created by docker because i was using a docker-compose file which involve the creation of an other custom network.

***This network was using a fixed ip range***:

```
networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 172.16.0.0/16
        gateway: 172.16.0.1
```

- At my home, the physical wifi network adapter was automaticly assigned using DHCP the address 192.168.0.X.
- But in the other place, the same wifi adapter get the address 172.16.0.x

Which collide with the custom docker network.

The solution was simply to change the IP of the custom docker network.

Answer (score 3):

You have to tell Docker to use a different subnet.  Edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and use something like this:

```
{
  "bip": "198.18.251.1/24",
  "default-address-pools": [
    {
      "base": "198.18.252.0/22",
      "size": 26
    }
  ]
}
```

Information is a bit hard to come by, but it looks like the `bip` option controls the IP and subnet assigned to the `docker0` interface, while `default-address-pools` controls the addresses used for the `br-*` interfaces.  You can omit `bip` in which case it will grab an allocation from the pool, and `bip` doesn't have to reside in the pool, as shown above.

The `size` is how big of a subnet to allocate to each Docker network.  For example if your `base` is a `/24` and you also set `size` to `24`, then you'll be able to create exactly one Docker network, and probably you'll only be able to run one Docker container.  If you try to start another you'll get the message `could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network`, which means you've run out of IP addresses in the pool.

In the above example I have allocated a `/22` (1024 addresses) with each network/container taking a `/26` (64 addresses) from that pool.  1024 ÷ 64 = 16, so you can run up to 16 Docker networks with this config (so max 16 containers running at the same time, or more if some of them share the same network).  Since I rarely have more than two or three running containers at any one time this is fine for me.

In my example I'm using part of the `198.18.0.0/15` subnet as listed in [RFC 3330](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3300) (but fully documented in [RFC 2544](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2544)) which is reserved for performance testing.  It is unlikely that these addresses will appear on the real Internet, and no professional network provider will use these subnets in their private network either, so in my opinion they are a good choice for use with Docker as conflicts are very unlikely.  But technically this is a misuse of this IP range so just be aware of potential future conflicts if you also choose to use these subnets.

The defaults [listed in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file) are:

```
{
  "bip": "",
  "default-address-pools": [
    {"base": "172.80.0.0/16", "size": 24},
    {"base": "172.90.0.0/16", "size": 24}
  ]
}
```

As mentioned above, the default empty `bip` means it will just grab an allocation from the pool, like any other network/container will.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I would not apply Clement solution because I have the network conflict only with my dev pc while the container is delivered to many server which are not affected. 
This problem in my opinion should be resolved as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52374482/4622767).
I tried this workaround:

1. I stopped the container with "docker-compose down" which destroys the bridge
2. Started the container while I'm on the "bad" network, so the container use another network

Since then, if I restart the container on any network it doesn't try to use the "bad" one, normally get the last used  one.