# ERROR: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space when starting my_project docker setup

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup docker and I`m getting the following error:

> ERROR: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space

What should I do to solve it,please?

Comment: You receive it during installation of docker or when trying to run some container?

Comment: Please provide the command you run and your docker-compose file.

Have you specified the network and renamed if after run it once? That error suggest a conflict. You could list the network `docker network ls` and delete the existing one should you find it `docker network rm my_network`.

Answer (score 72):

Could you provide us with the command you have run as well as your `docker-compose.yml` file please?

The error you are encountering is suggesting you have a network address conflict. To check that you could run: `docker network ls` to list all the docker network running currently on your machine.

Once you have identified the culprit you should be able to remove it with the following command: `docker network rm my_network` (where `my_network` is the one you have created initially)

Alternatively combine those with the command provided by @Adán Escobar

Comment: This answer will recreate the IP address, but it's not guaranteed to avoid conflicts. You could still get a conflicting IP address unless you configure daemon.json to avoid the conflicting subnets. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78064392/2415524

Answer (score 35):

```
docker network prune
```

Worked for me.

Comment: What will happen if You delete networks, that are used but other containers? `docker system prune` then?

Answer (score 17):

if you don't mind delete all docker networks, you could run

```
docker network rm $(docker network ls -q)
```

Answer (score 7):

remove one or more network in the result of `docker network ls` with `docker network rm ID`

Answer (score 5):

Most likely You try to create a network, which overlaps with an already running container. You may have a docker-compose.yaml file which defines a network with a fixed address.

```
networks:
        hosting:
            ipv4_address: 192.168.200.80
```

The grep Your interfaces

```
$ ip addr | grep 192.168
    inet 192.168.2.2/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global noprefixroute enp1s0
    inet 192.168.16.1/20 brd 192.168.31.255 scope global br-425bf896730c
    inet 192.168.192.1/20 brd 192.168.207.255 scope global br-7bf61cfc0b5a
    inet 192.168.48.1/20 brd 192.168.63.255 scope global br-ad263cc0cb22
```

Notice that 192.168.192.1/20 overlaps with 192.168.200.80

Now br-7bf61cfc0b5a means that the docker network id is 7bf61cfc0b5a

```
$ docker network ls | grep 7bf61cfc0b5a
7bf61cfc0b5a   openvpn_default          bridge    local
```

Close openvpn and remove the network

Now the network with the fixed address can go up.
Afterwards, openvpn can be started again, and now it will have another automatically assigned IP range.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your docker use a subnet 195.*

Change your ip adresses 172.* to 192.* in your docker-compose.yaml.